# How can I get result from string formula as integer

Tags: vb.net

How I can get result value from this string formula :

```
Dim Formula As String

Formula = "((5000 / 30) * (22 + 6)) + ((5000 / 30 / 8) * (20))"

Dim Result As Integer 

Result = ?????
```

How can I get an integer result value? It's 5083.33

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit simpler - use the `.Compute` method of the `DataTable`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim r = dt.Compute("((5000 / 30) * (22 + 6)) + ((5000 / 30 / 8) * (20))", Nothing)
    Debug.Print(r.ToString)
End Sub
```

Result in Immediate Window

> 5083.33333333333

Comment: This is actually a terrible answer.  While it does the thing in a short number of characters - the problem domain, "evaluate a mathematical expression represented as a string", does not fit the solution domain of "DataTables".

Comment: @SamAxe I am trying to understand your comment but it is not clear to me. What is the meaning of "does not fit the solution domain of "DataTables". "? Do you mean there is a limit to what `.Compute` can handle?

Comment: @Mary: no, I mean that taking a dependency on `System.Data.DataTable` doesn't make sense when the question has absolutely nothing to do with `DataTable`s.  While the answer might solve the *immediate* problem, it does nothing to further the knowledge in the problem domain.  Think of it like this:  if the question were "how do I light a camp fire" and the answer was "grab a magnifying glass and focus the sunlight" that would solve the *immediate* problem, but certainly does nothing to further anyone's understanding of proper camp-fire ignition techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every body,

I got the CODE right now as following :-

Just you Can Do ..... >>>  NumericBox1 = EvaluateExpr(TextBox2.Text)

```
Private Function IsEmptyStack(ByVal AStack As Stack) As Boolean
    Return (AStack.Count = 0)
End Function

Private Function IsOperator(ByVal AChar As Char) As Boolean
    Return "^*/+-".Contains(AChar)
End Function

Private Function CompareOperators(ByVal Op1 As Char, ByVal Op2 As Char) As Integer
    If Not (IsOperator(Op1) And IsOperator(Op2)) Then
        Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1001, "CompareOperators", "Operator(s) not suppoerted")
    End If

    Select Case Op1
        Case "^"c
            If Op2 = "^"c Then
                Return 0
            Else
                Return 1
            End If
        Case "*"c, "/"c
            Select Case Op2
                Case "^"c
                    Return -1
                Case "*"c, "/"c
                    Return 0
                Case "+"c, "-"c
                    Return 1
            End Select
        Case "+"c, "-"c
            Select Case Op2
                Case "^"c, "*"c, "/"c
                    Return -1
                Case "+"c, "-"c
                    Return 0
            End Select
    End Select
End Function

Private Function InfixToPostfix(ByVal InfixExpression As String) As String
    Dim Infix As String
    Dim Postfix As String
    Dim InfixIndex As Integer
    Dim InfixLen As Integer
    Dim AChar As Char
    Dim APeek As String
    Dim ANumber As String
    Dim MathStack As New Stack

    Infix = InfixExpression.Trim()
    If Infix = "" Then
        Return ""
    End If

    Infix = Infix & ")"
    ANumber = ""
    Postfix = ""

    InfixLen = Len(Infix)         '- 1
    InfixIndex = 0
    MathStack.Clear()

    MathStack.Push("(")

    Do While (Not IsEmptyStack(MathStack)) And (InfixIndex <= InfixLen)
        'AChar = Mid$(Infix, InfixIndex, 1)
        AChar = Infix(InfixIndex)
        If Char.IsDigit(AChar) Then
            ANumber = ANumber & AChar
        ElseIf AChar = "(" Then
            If ANumber <> "" Then
                Postfix = Postfix & ANumber & " "
                ANumber = ""
            End If
            MathStack.Push(AChar)
        ElseIf IsOperator(AChar) Then
            If ANumber <> "" Then
                Postfix = Postfix & ANumber & " "
                ANumber = ""
            End If
            APeek = MathStack.Peek
            If IsOperator(APeek) Then
                Do While CompareOperators(APeek, AChar) >= 0
                    APeek = MathStack.Pop
                    Postfix = Postfix & APeek
                    APeek = MathStack.Peek
                    If Not IsOperator(APeek) Then Exit Do
                Loop
            End If
            MathStack.Push(AChar)
        ElseIf AChar = ")" Then
            If ANumber <> "" Then
                Postfix = Postfix & ANumber & " "
                ANumber = ""
            End If
            APeek = MathStack.Peek
            Do While APeek <> "("
                APeek = MathStack.Pop
                Postfix = Postfix & APeek
                APeek = MathStack.Peek
            Loop
            MathStack.Pop()
        End If
        InfixIndex = InfixIndex + 1
    Loop
    If Not IsEmptyStack(MathStack) Then
        Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1002, "InfixToPostfix", "Invalid infix expression")
    Else
        InfixToPostfix = Postfix
    End If
End Function

Private Function PerformOperation(ByVal Number1 As Double, ByVal Number2 As Double, ByVal AOperator As Char) As Double
    Select Case AOperator
        Case "+"c
            Return Number1 + Number2
        Case "-"c
            Return Number1 - Number2
        Case "*"c
            Return Number1 * Number2
        Case "/"c
            If Number2 = 0 Then
                Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1004, "EvaluatePostfix", "Division by zero")
            Else
                Return Number1 / Number2
            End If
        Case "^"c
            Return Number1 ^ Number2
        Case Else
            Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1001, "CompareOperators", "Operator not suppoerted")
    End Select
End Function

Private Function EvaluatePostfix(ByVal PostfixExpression As String) As Double
    Dim Postfix As String
    Dim ANumber As String
    Dim AChar As Char
    Dim PostfixIndex As Long
    Dim PostfixLen As Long
    Dim Num1 As Double
    Dim Num2 As Double
    Dim NumResult As Double
    Dim MathStack As New Stack

    Postfix = Trim$(PostfixExpression)
    If Postfix = "" Then
        Return 0.0
    End If
    Postfix = Postfix & "="

    ANumber = ""
    PostfixLen = Len(Postfix)
    PostfixIndex = 0
    MathStack.Clear()

    Do While PostfixIndex <= PostfixLen
        AChar = Postfix(PostfixIndex)
        If AChar = " " Then
            If ANumber <> "" Then
                MathStack.Push(CDbl(ANumber))
                ANumber = ""
            End If
        ElseIf Char.IsDigit(AChar) Then
            ANumber = ANumber & AChar
        ElseIf AChar = "=" Then
            If ANumber <> "" Then
                MathStack.Push(CDbl(ANumber))
                ANumber = ""
            End If
            If MathStack.Count = 1 Then
                Return MathStack.Pop
            Else
                Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1003, "EvaluatePostfix", "Invalid postfix expression")
            End If
        ElseIf IsOperator(AChar) Then
            If ANumber <> "" Then
                MathStack.Push(CDbl(ANumber))
                ANumber = ""
            End If
            If IsEmptyStack(MathStack) Then
                Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1003, "EvaluatePostfix", "Invalid postfix expression")
            Else
                Num2 = MathStack.Pop
                If IsEmptyStack(MathStack) Then
                    Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 1003, "EvaluatePostfix", "Invalid postfix expression")
                Else
                    Num1 = MathStack.Pop
                    NumResult = PerformOperation(Num1, Num2, AChar)
                    MathStack.Push(NumResult)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        PostfixIndex = PostfixIndex + 1
    Loop
End Function

Public Function EvaluateExpr(ByVal AExpr As String) As String
    Dim PostfixExpr As String

    AExpr = AExpr.Trim
    If AExpr = "" Then Return ""

    PostfixExpr = InfixToPostfix(AExpr)
    Return EvaluatePostfix(PostfixExpr)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't really qualify as an answer, but I thought it would be fun to re-write that big code block using more modern techniques. I've done this right in the reply window, so there are probably several errors. It's worth noting, though, how much shorter this is.

We could have even more fun, and probably perform better, by also re-writing the code to think in terms of breaking apart the string into **tokens**, rather than by character.

```
Public Module Math
    'Reverse precedence order, so higher precedence has higher index       
    Private operators As String =  "-+/*^"   

    Private Function CompareOperators(Op1 As Char, Op2 As Char) As Integer        
        Dim Op1Value As Integer = operators.IndexOf(Op1) 
        Dim Op2Value As Integer = operators.IndexOf(Op2) 

        If Op1Value = -1 Then Throw New Exception($"Unsupported operator {Op1} detected")
        If Op2Value = -1 Then Throw New Excpetion($"Unsupported operator {Op2} detected")

        'The \ 2 adjusts for same precedence of +- and */
        Return (Op1Value \ 2).CompareTo(Op2Value \ 2)
    End Function

    Private Function InfixToPostfix(InfixExpression As String) As String
        If String.IsNullOrWhitesapce(InfixExpression) Then Return ""

        InfixExpression = InfixExpression.Trim() & ")"
        Dim result As New StringBuilder()

        Dim MathStack As New Stack(Of Char)()              
        Dim ANumber As String = ""       
        Dim Index As Integer  = 0

        MathStack.Push("("c)

        While MathStack.Count > 0 AndAlso Index <= InfixExpression.Length)
            Dim AChar As Char = InfixExpression(Index)
            If Char.IsDigit(AChar) Then
                ANumber &= ANumber & AChar
            ElseIf AChar = "("c Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ANumber) Then
                    result.Append(ANumber).Append(" ")
                    ANumber = ""
                End If
                MathStack.Push(AChar)
            ElseIf IsOperator(AChar) Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ANumber) Then
                    result.Append(ANumber).Append(" ")
                    ANumber = ""
                End If
                Dim APeek As Char = MathStack.Peek()
                If IsOperator(APeek) Then
                    While CompareOperators(APeek, AChar) >= 0
                        APeek = MathStack.Pop()
                        result.Append(APeek)
                        APeek = MathStack.Peek
                        If Not IsOperator(APeek) Then Exit While
                    End While
                End If
                MathStack.Push(AChar)
            ElseIf AChar = ")"c Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ANumber) Then
                    result.Append(ANumber).Append(" ")
                    ANumber = ""
                End If
                APeek = MathStack.Peek()
                While APeek <> "("c
                    APeek = MathStack.Pop()
                    result.Append(APeek)
                    APeek = MathStack.Peek()
                End While
                MathStack.Pop()
            End If
            Index += 1
        End While

        If MathStack.Count > 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("Invalid infix expression: stack is not empty")
        End If

        Return result.ToString()
    End Function

    Private Function PerformOperation(Number1 As Double, Number2 As Double, AOperator As Char) As Double
        Select Case AOperator
            Case "+"c
                Return Number1 + Number2
            Case "-"c
                Return Number1 - Number2
            Case "*"c
                Return Number1 * Number2
            Case "/"c
                'We could detect Number2 = 0 here, but appropriate response is throwing the same DivideByZeroException the framework will do for us anyway
                Return Number1 / Number2
            Case "^"c
                Return Number1 ^ Number2
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception($"Operator {AOperator} not supported")
        End Select
    End Function

    Private Function EvaluatePostfix(Expression As String) As Double
        Dim result As Double = 0R
        If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Expression) Then Return result

        Expression = Expression.Trim() & "="

        Dim MathStack As New Stack(Of Double)()
        Dim ANumber As String = ""

        Dim Index As Integer = 0
        Do While Index <= Expression.Length
            AChar = Expression(Index)
            If AChar = " "c Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ANumber) Then
                    MathStack.Push(CDbl(ANumber))
                    ANumber = ""
                End If
            ElseIf Char.IsDigit(AChar) Then
                ANumber = ANumber & AChar
            ElseIf AChar = "="c Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ANumber) Then
                    MathStack.Push(CDbl(ANumber))
                    ANumber = ""
                End If
                If MathStack.Count = 1 Then Return MathStack.Pop()
                Throw New Exception("Invalid postfix expression")
            ElseIf IsOperator(AChar) Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ANumber) Then
                    MathStack.Push(CDbl(ANumber))
                    ANumber = ""
                End If
                If MathStack.Count < 2 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Invalid postfix expression: insufficient stack")
                End If
                Dim Num2 As Double = MathStack.Pop()
                MathStack.Push(PerformOperation(MathStack.Pop(), Num2))
            End If
            Index += 1
        Loop
    End Function

    Public Function EvaluateExpr(AExpr As String) As String
        If String.IsNullOrWhitespacE(AExpr) Then Return ""
        Return EvaluatePostfix(InfixToPostfix(AExpr))
    End Function
End Module
```

Wanted to do the token option for more fun:

```
Public Module Math
    'Reverse precedence order, so higher precedence has higher index       
    Private operators As String = "()-+/*^"

    Private Function IsOperator(AChar As Char) As Boolean
        Return operators.Contains(AChar)
    End Function

    Private Function CompareOperators(Op1 As Char, Op2 As Char) As Integer
        Dim Op1Value As Integer = operators.IndexOf(Op1)
        Dim Op2Value As Integer = operators.IndexOf(Op2)

        If Op1Value = -1 Then Throw New Exception($"Unsupported operator '{Op1}' detected")
        If Op2Value = -1 Then Throw New Exception($"Unsupported operator '{Op2}' detected")

        'The \ 2 adjusts for same precedence of +- and */
        Return (Op1Value \ 2).CompareTo(Op2Value \ 2)
    End Function

    Private Iterator Function Tokenize(input As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Dim buffer As String = ""
        For Each c As Char In input
            If Char.IsWhitespace(c) Then
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(buffer) Then Continue For
                Yield buffer
                buffer = ""
            ElseIf Char.IsDigit(c) OrElse c = "."c Then
                buffer &= c 'Don't worry about validating good numbers at this level. Just check the characters
            ElseIf c = "-"c Then ' could be operator or negative sign
                If buffer.Length > 0 Then 'was an operator
                    Yield buffer
                    buffer = ""
                    Yield c.ToString()
                Else 'Not sure yet -- treat as digit for now
                    buffer &= c
                End If
            ElseIf operators.Contains(c) OrElse "()".Contains(c) Then
                If buffer.Length > 0 Then
                    Yield buffer
                    buffer = ""
                End If
                Yield c.ToString()
            Else
                Throw New Exception($"Unexpected character '{c}' in input")
            End If
        Next c
        If buffer.Length > 0 Then Yield buffer
    End Function

    Private Iterator Function InfixToPostfix(tokens As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of String)

        Dim buffer As New Stack(Of String)()
        Dim temp As Double

        For Each token As String In tokens
            If Double.TryParse(token, temp) Then
                Yield token
                'Need to account for "(" better
            ElseIf token = "(" Then
                buffer.Push(token)
            ElseIf operators.Contains(token) AndAlso token <> ")" Then
                If buffer.Count = 0 Then
                    buffer.Push(token)
                ElseIf CompareOperators(token, buffer.Peek()) > 0 Then
                    buffer.Push(token)
                Else
                    While CompareOperators(token, buffer.Peek()) <= 0
                        Dim tok As String = buffer.Pop()
                        If Not "()".Contains(tok) Then Yield tok
                        If buffer.Count = 0 Then Exit While
                    End While
                    buffer.Push(token)
                End If
            ElseIf token = ")" Then
                Dim valid As Boolean = False
                While buffer.Count > 0
                    Dim tok As String = buffer.Pop()
                    If tok = "(" Then
                        valid = True
                        Exit While
                    Else
                        Yield tok
                    End If
                End While
                If Not valid Then Throw New Exception("Unbalanced parentheses in expression (missing matching '(' character)")
            Else
                Throw New Exception($"Unknown token type '{token}'")
            End If
        Next token

        While buffer.Count > 0
            Dim tok As String = buffer.Pop()
            If Not "()".Contains(tok) Then Yield tok
        End While
    End Function

    Private Function PerformOperation(Number1 As Double, Number2 As Double, AOperator As Char) As Double
        Select Case AOperator
            Case "+"c
                Return Number1 + Number2
            Case "-"c
                Return Number1 - Number2
            Case "*"c
                Return Number1 * Number2
            Case "/"c
                'We could detect Number2 = 0 here, but appropriate response is throwing the same DivideByZeroException the framework will do for us anyway
                Return Number1 / Number2
            Case "^"c
                Return Number1 ^ Number2
            Case Else
                Throw New Exception($"Operator {AOperator} not supported")
        End Select
    End Function

    Private Function EvaluatePostfix(tokens As IEnumerable(Of String)) As Double
        Dim result As Double = 0R
        Dim buffer As New Stack(Of Double)()
        Dim temp As Double

        For Each token As String In tokens
            If Double.TryParse(token, temp) Then
                buffer.Push(temp)
            ElseIf buffer.Count < 2 Then
                Throw New Exception("Invalid postfix expression")
            Else
                temp = buffer.Pop()
                temp = PerformOperation(buffer.Pop(), temp, token(0))
                buffer.Push(temp)
            End If
        Next token

        If buffer.Count > 1 Then Throw New Exception("Invalid expression: extra items in the buffer")
        If buffer.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception("Invalid expression: no result")
        Return buffer.Pop()
    End Function

    Public Function Evaluate(input As String) As Double
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) Then Return 0R
        Dim tokens = Tokenize(input)
        tokens = InfixToPostfix(tokens)
        Return EvaluatePostfix(tokens)
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear, but really your code not working with me!! I Don't know the reason.

Comment: probably lots of them... again, I wrote that for fun and typed it right into the reply window, with no testing or debugging of anything. But since I was pulled back here, I'm also playing with a tokenizer version

Comment: And a tokenizer option is now up :) This has a little more testing, and works for at least the few test expressions I played with.